# Pi Zero W connect (tether?) to android via USB or OTG

Tags: pi-zero-w

Apologies for the slightly long winded question, the summary is: how can I connect (tether?) a pi Zero W to an Android phone with USB or OTG

**Context.**  I use a pi zero w to take time lapse photos (a cricket scoreboard) and FTP these up to a website so people not at the game can keep up to date. Currently I have set up a hotspot on the phone (a Motorola G4) and I have modified the pi to have hard coded the hotspot details, so it connects automatically on boot

```
sudo leafpad /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

then add

```
network={
    ssid="phones_ssid"
    psk="hotspot_password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="location2"
}
```

I can run an android app on the phone (called Network IP scanner) that tells me the local IP address of the hotspot

This all works great, however it requires me to know the hotspot details before we get out in the field and hard code them.  I would like the pi zero w to be able to plug into any phone with a hotspot and then be able to access the web server via the phones screen so that I can either run a network of these using my colleagues phones or indeed give the pi to people when I am not playing!

thanks for your interest, I have googled tethering USB0/ethernet etc etc but I'm not really getting anywhere...

Comment: Guessing, you would need an custom application on all phones that would engage the RaspberrbyPi / USB device.  Not very convenient.  On top of that, I don't believe getting network credentials to your custom application will be easy.  As sharing that information between the HotSpot application and this new custom application you need to write sounds like a security risk that  Android should not permit. But this is guessing.  Alternatively, consider writing code on the Pi to search through all available SSIDs (different phones) and using the 1st one it finds for which it has credentials for.

Comment: @st2000 on Ubuntu, if I plug an Android device with tethering on or (this really surprised me) an iPhone, it will tether via USB and see it as a wired network adapter